# Throwing exception with coroutine crashes app instead of handling failure in try/catch block

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines

**view model :**

```
val link: String? = null
if(link.isNullOrEmpty()){
    throw IllegalArgumentException(mApplication.resources.getString(R.string.server_in_maintenance_please_try_again_later))
}
```

**fargment :**

```
try{
    //calling the viewmodel function
}catch (e:IllegalArgumentException){
   Toast.makeText(requireContext(), e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}catch (e:Exception){
   Toast.makeText(requireContext(), e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

I assigned null into the "link" to demonstrate calling from the API when the API's server is in maintenance or shut down temporarily..

this is the stack trace -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4
Process: com.amagen.supercheap, PID: 12491
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MY MESSAGE FROM RESOURCE FILE
    at com.amagen.supercheap.MainActivityViewModel$createSuperItemsTable$2$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivityViewModel.kt:112)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **[CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/index.html)** where you a starting Coroutine and inside that `exceptionHandler` variable you will get the exception details. It will also prevent app from crashing.

Sample code below

```
private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { context, exception ->
    exception.message?.let { Log.d("Error", it) }
}


lifecycleScope.launch(kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers.IO + exceptionHandler) {
}
```

Comment: when im throwing the exception in the CoroutineExceptionHandler my app is still crashing (with the same stack trace as before).
I want to notify the user with toast that the operation is temp not available..

Comment: Why do you want to throw exception at first place? I mean if link is set to null initially just use link object as link?. for a Null Safety and you are good to go.  In case not using this just catch the exception they way i describer in answer you don't need to throw the exception.

Comment: Please refer to this link

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

Comment: this is more complex than that, I got a job (coroutine scope) in the few fragments that execute the same function in the view model.
in the view model function there are few more job, each one relies on the other, if one of them is cancelled or paused, i want the parent job to notify the user that the operation he just tried to do is not available at the moment.
right now I managed to catch the exception in one of the childs but the parent is still not aware that one of his child jobs has been cancelled

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you catch errors in coroutines this way?

```
private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(dispatcher)
private val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, _ ->
    Logger.e("Caught : Exception ...")
}
 
coroutineScope.launch(handler) {
            
}
```